# Cloning and moving traits

Tags: multithreading, rust, clone, traits, lifetime

I'd like to be able to move a cloned version of an object that implements trait `Foo` into various threads. I cannot seem to figure out how this is achieved. I've tried cloning and moving a `Box<Foo>` and specifying the parameter as a generic, but cannot seem make the compiler happy.

My first attempt:

```
use std::thread;

pub trait Foo {
    fn bar();
}

pub struct Thing;

impl Thing {
    pub fn something(handler: Box<Foo>) {
        let handler_1 = handler.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            Thing::another_thread(handler_1)
        });
    }

    fn another_thread(handler: Box<Foo>) { }
}
```

Resulted in the following errors:

```
error: no method named clone found for type Box<Foo + 'static> in the current scope
error: the trait core::marker::Send is not implemented for the type Foo [E0277]
```

Next I tried writing it as a generic parameter...

```
use std::thread;

pub trait Foo {
    fn bar();
}

pub struct Thing;

impl Thing {
    pub fn something<T: Foo + Clone + Send>(handler: T) {
        let handler_1 = handler.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            Thing::another_thread(handler_1)
        });
    }

    fn another_thread<T: Foo>(handler: T) { }
}
```

Received the following error:

```
error: the parameter type T may not live long enough [E0310]
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound T: 'static...
```

Now we've reached the point where I'm lost and I start poking `<'a>` into every crevice hoping it solves the problem. But, unfortunately, I have no idea what the syntax is for what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'static`...

That looks like this:

```rust
pub fn something<T: 'static + Foo + Clone + Send>(handler: T)
```

which compiles.

In case you are unfamiliar with this syntax, it means that whatever concrete type of `T` is picked, it must outlive the `'static` lifetime. This includes any interior references / lifetimes the concrete type may have.